# How to convert a char to int in C during initialization

Tags: c++, types, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I want to compare two char types in C++. I tried `cout<<"x"=="x";` to see the result and it wont work(which I believe is normal), so I tried converting it by trying `int letter = "x"` to try to compare it by it ASCII number. This gets me the error;

error:invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

Shouldn't this work? If not, what should I be doing?

Comment: **Note**: **`"5"`** is a **string**, `'5'` is a **`cha`r**, **`5`** is a **`int`**. all are different.

Comment: Try: `cout<< 'x' == 'x';` it will work.

Answer (score 5):

`"x"` gives you a nul-terminated array of characters `{'x','\0'}`.

Use `'x'` if you want a single `char`

Answer (score 2):

- `"x"` is an array of chars - string - (2 bytes - one for char `x`, one for char `\0` nul)
- `'x'` is char - variable represented by 1 byte in memory.

Assigning `"x"` to an `int` variable is an obvious mistake.

Try `'x'` instead of `"x"`: `int letter = 'x';` should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using double quotes around your characters.

Double quotes are of type const char*, not type char

Try

```
int letter = 'x';
```